# wpf use bitmapimage as source for TransformedBitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

in my wpf i create an imagebox called "image_box"

on Window_Loaded i load my imagebox with

```
image_box.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/pic.png"));
```

I have next code on Rotate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

```
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
bmp.BeginInit();
bmp.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/pic.png");
bmp.EndInit();

TransformedBitmap myRotatedBitmapSource = new TransformedBitmap();
myRotatedBitmapSource.BeginInit();
myRotatedBitmapSource.Source = bmp;
myRotatedBitmapSource.Transform = new RotateTransform(90);
myRotatedBitmapSource.EndInit();
image_box.Source = myRotatedBitmapSource;
```

all I want in this code is

bmp.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/pic.png");

to use

location of image_box like

```
bmp.UriSource = image_box.Source;
```

i try

```
Uri ur = new Uri(image_box.Source.ToString());
...
bmp.UriSource = ur;
```

but on second click i got invalid url

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
image_box.Source.ToString()
```

only returns a valid URI string when `Source` is a BitmapImage. However, in the second call of your Click handler, Source is a `TransformedBitmap`.

You should simply reuse the original source image and increase (or decrease) the rotation angle by multiples of 90.

```
private BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/pic.png"));
private double rotation = 0;

private void Rotate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rotation += 90;
    image_box.Source = new TransformedBitmap(source, new RotateTransform(rotation));
}
```

Or also keep the TransformedBitmap and only change its `Transform` property:

```
private BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/pic.png"));
private double rotation = 0;
private TransformedBitmap transformedBitmap =
    new TransformedBitmap(source, new RotateTransform(rotation));
...
image_box.Source = transformedBitmap; // call this once
...

private void Rotate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rotation += 90;
    transformedBitmap.Transform = new RotateTransform(rotation);
}
```

Comment: the problem is I want to use one button rotate, one button flip image and combined Click(). how to do it ?

Comment: By combining the appropriate transforms, e.g. in a TransformGroup. Note that TransformedBitmap only supports rotations by multiples of 90 degrees and scaling transforms.